# Various translations of the English verb “close”

Tags: difference, verb, verb-choice

I am trying to organize my knowledge about the various translations of the English verbs *close*, and find out which German word is most suitable for typical usages.

- When closing something like a **door**, one may use *eine Tür schließen* or *eine Tür zumachen* (is there any difference?). I’ve also encountered *eine Tür verschließen*, which is translated the same according to wiktionary. Google translate also adds *eine Tür abschließen*, but I believe this is more like locking or sealing a door?
- When closing something like a **deal**, one may use *einen Deal schließen*, but I have not encountered *einen Deal zumachen* or *einen Deal verschließen* at all. I have encountered, however, the form *einen Deal abschließen* — does it mean the same thing?
- When closing something like a **financial gap**, one may use *die finanzielle Lücke schließen*, but *verschließen*, *abschließen* and *zumachen* won’t work here.
- I couldn’t find the appropriate term for closing a **file**.

I guess I can keep going with that list, but that won’t be productive; I am wondering whether some thumb rules exist, such that will ease wording (other than “always use *schließen*”), or some fine-tuining of the definitions of those similar verbs.

Comment: »Eine Tür verschließen« is wrong. You can »mit einer Tür ein Zimmer verschließen.« (close a room with a door). You only can *verschließen* a container (a jar, a can, a box, a room, a house). But you can't *verschließen* the cover, lid, cap, top, door etc. that you use to close the hollow thing that has an opening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you should open up more than one question for it ;)

However:

*(eine Tür) verschließen* can be used for both: closing a door or locking a door, whereas *(eine Tür) schließen* just means closing.

*(eine Tür) zumachen* and *(eine Tür) schließen* are pretty much the same, but *zumachen* is not the best German — Not sure whether you can say that in English, but it’s a bit like *to make a door closed*.

In case of deal, in most cases the prefix *ab* is used. So *einen Vertrag (ab)schließen* with slightly different meaning in terms of the view at the contract. Without the prefix, it’s more like partners — with the prefix it’s more like customer-realtionship.

When *closing a finacial gap*, you could also say *zumachen* — but remeber, it’s bad German and should be used — but surely you will read/hear it some time ;) So keeping at verb *schließen*, in this case use it without a prefix. There are a lot of other, sometimes symbolic, terms for this. E.g. a couple of days I’ve seen *eine finanzielle Lücke füllen* which implies something like somebody is using a lorry to fill the gap up.

*Closing a file* again without any prefix in most cases. Could be translated as *`einen Fall/eine Akte schließen* (well, *abschließen* would be also fine here with minimal differences most Germans would even recognize) but it’s *eine Datei schließen*.

I hope I didn’t confuse you even more ;)
Well … a try to create a rule of the thumb:
If you look or if you finish something, it’s *abschließen*. If you just close something, maybe like a jar of jam, it’s either *verschließen* or just *schließen*.

Comment: There's also "mit etwas abschließen", which matches your rule of thumb for *finish something*. I'm not sure though whether abschließen in this sense and in the sense of locking a door are actually of the same origin (schließen vs. Schluss).

Comment: Yepp about the `abschlißen` thing. Not sure about the origin, but doubt that they differ in this case.

Comment: "abschließen" has many meanings: "einen Vertrag abschließen" is completly different from "ein Auto abschließen" and this again with "mit dem Leben abschließen"

Comment: `(eine Tür) verschließen / eine verschlossene Tür` does imply that the door will be / is locked and `die Tür zumachen` is pretty common

Answer (score -1):

In Yiddish we have "verhacken türen und fenster" which means the doors and windows are bolted and shuttered, as though in anticipation of a pogrom. I don't know if the verb is used that way in any other dialect. Otherwise *zumachen* or *vermachen* are probably the preferred terms if you're talking about closing a door, with *schliessen* being an alternative.

Comment: `vermachen` in German is in most cases translatable to `bequeath` -- at least if I can trust my dictionary ;) It's about giving somebody something, after e.g. somebody died.

Comment: yeah, the prefixes don't always take you in exactly the same direction. For "bequeath", we have "abschreiben", which also works for any transfer of ownership. Oddly enough, if the bailiff comes to confiscate your merchandise, that is also "abschreiben".